# Heading with php foreach and sql group by

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if this is possible without a second sql query, but I figured it would be good to ask first.

I have SQL query with a GROUP BY clause. Within the foreach loop to display the results, I want to insert a heading for each condition. Is it possible to do with just the one query?

ie.

Non Taproom Only

```
DATA
DATA
DATA
```

Taproom Only

```
DATA
DATA
DATA
```

The SQL Code:

```
SELECT 
      `Keg`.`content_type_id`, `Keg`.`is_taproom_only`, count(content_type_id), `ContentType`.`id`, `ContentType`.`name`     
FROM 
      `kegdb`.`kegs` AS `Keg` 
LEFT JOIN
      `kegdb`.`content_types` AS `ContentType` 
      ON (`Keg`.`content_type_id` = `ContentType`.`id`) 
WHERE 
       `status_type_id` = 6     
GROUP BY 
      is_taproom_only, content_type_id 
ORDER BY 
      `is_taproom_only` ASC, `ContentType`.`name` ASC
```

Comment: Show your SQL query, please. Additionally you may use the `implode()` function in PHP to insert more than one row at a time with a single SQL statement.

Comment: Where is the heading information meant to be coming from? Another database table?

Comment: It comes from the GROUP BY clause. Each group should have its own heading/title.

Comment: Use a variable to store the group heading. When you loop over the results if the heading in the row and the variable do not match, then print the heading, else don't. Assign the heading in the row to the variable at the end in each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, assuming your data is going to be *something* like this:

```
is_taproom_only, content_type_id, content_type_name
-----------------------
NonTaproom, content_type_id, content_type_name
NonTaproom, content_type_id, content_type_name
NonTaproom, content_type_id, content_type_name
TaproomOnly, content_type_id, content_type_name
TaproomOnly, content_type_id, content_type_name
TaproomOnly, content_type_id, content_type_name
```

you can (as air4x said in the comments above) use a variable to store the heading and while looping through the results, only print the heading if it's different from the previously stored heading.

Note: This approach will only work if your results are ordered by the heading value (which I can see they are).

PHP code will look something like this:

```
$is_taproom_only = '';

foreach $rows as $row {

    echo ($is_taproom_only <> $row['is_taproom_only']) ? $row['is_taproom_only'] : ''; //only print if they're different
    $is_taproom_only = $row['is_taproom_only']; //store for the next iteration

    //print other data
    echo $row['content_type_id'];
    echo $row['content_type_name'];

}
```